# How to have two separate query-sets under the same class based view EX: User Profile and Friends

Tags: python, django, django-models, pki

On an  earlier question I asked: How to have two separate querysets under the same class based view. The initial problem was a simple due to a syntax error but after fixing it i got  `:get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'` I  believe it to be a problem on how i wrote my views.

EDIT: Clarifying the issue: is how to have two querysets one calling User's pk info and one making a list of users under the same class.

## views.py

```
class ViewProfile(generic.ListView):
        model = Post
        template_name = 'accounts/profile.html'
        def view_profile(request, pk=None):
            if pk:
                user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
            else:
                user = request.user
            kwargs = {'user': request.user}
            return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', kwargs)
    def get(self, request):
        users =User.objects.all()
        object_list= Post.objects.filter(owner =self.request.user).order_by('-timestamp')
        args ={'object_list':object_list,'users':users}
        return render (request, self.template_name, args)
```

## urls.py

```
# profilepage
        url(r'^profile/$', views.ViewProfile.as_view(), name='view_profile'),

    # profilepage
    url(r'^profile/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ViewProfile.as_view(), name='view_profile_with_pk'),
```

## profile

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <h1>Friends</h1>
      {%for user in users %}
      <a href="{% url 'accounts:view_profile_with_pk' pk=user.pk  %}">
        <h3>{{user.username}}</h3>
      </a>

      {%endfor%}
</div>
```

Comment: What is that `view_profile` method for? What do you think is going to call it?

Comment: Remove the `/` after the `?` in your second URL pattern.

Comment: You are probably looking are the wrong `get()`: `def get(self, request)` doesn't accept `pk=`, but gets passed a kwarg `pk` from `r'^profile/(?/P<pk>\d+)/$'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you see, your `view_profile_with_pk` url pattern takes a `pk` paramter:

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ViewProfile.as_view(), name='view_profile_with_pk')
```

But then in your `ViewProfile` view you have configured your `get()` method like:

```
def get(self, request):
    # ...
```

You can clearly notice that `get()` takes **exactly** two parameters, which are `self` and `request`. There is no `pk` anywhere. So Django doesn't know about it.

Yet.

You can add `*args` and `**kwargs` arguments to the `get()` function, which will take care of your url parameters:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # ...
```

And then you can freely get your `pk` inside the function:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    pk = kwargs.get('pk')  # <<<

    users = User.objects.all()
    object_list = Post.objects.filter(owner=request.user).order_by('-timestamp')
    context = {'object_list': object_list, 'users': users}

    return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

But I don't understand why you have defined the `view_profile` function, while you can implement it's logic inside the `get()` function:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    pk = kwargs.get('pk')
    owner = User.objects.get(pk=pk) if pk else request.user  # <<<

    users = User.objects.all()
    object_list = Post.objects.filter(owner=owner).order_by('-timestamp')
    # ________________________________^
    context = {'object_list': object_list, 'users': users}

    return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

This will work, until you provide a non-existing `pk` to the view. This will result an exception. You can fix that by using [`get_object_or_404()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404):

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    pk = kwargs.get('pk')
    owner = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk) if pk else request.user  # <<<

    users = User.objects.all()
    object_list = Post.objects.filter(owner=owner).order_by('-timestamp')
    context = {'object_list': object_list, 'users': users}

    return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

Now you should have a fully functional view.

**EDIT:**

As you've just stated, the view returns the same `User` data. This is because of:

```
users = User.objects.all()
```

This line is meaningless, because every time the user sends a request to your view, he will get a `users` property in the `context`, which just holds all the users in your database.

A possible and more meaningful solution will be to attach the current user to this property:

```
# ...
context = {'object_list': object_list, 'user': owner}
# _______________________________________^

return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

Now the view will return the `Post`s and their related `User`.

Comment: Thank you that worked. But saw that it only gives me the post of the linked person the actual account user info stays the same. Do you know why?

Comment: @Migdotcom As far as I understand, you want to have the current `User` in the `context`? Because now I realized that `users = User.objects.all()` is useless, cause it just returns all the users. I'll now update my answer with possible solution of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Hi can you try like this

```
def view_profile(request, *args, **kwargs, pk=None):
        if 'pk' in kwargs:
            user = User.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])
        else:
            user = request.user
        kwargs = {'user': request.user}
        return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', kwargs)
```